# How to implement and call multiple php functions?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

The following is code that I have put together with some help from SO.  I am trying to be able to implement the `$select` statement, as well as the `$search` statement on the same page.  The `$select` statement works fine, but I do not know how to call the `$search` statement to execute when  the user searches using the form within the code.  Does anyone know how to do this, or can you redirect me to a good tutorial with how forms interact with php?

```
<?php
require 'db/connect.php';

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC");

$search = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE '%$_REQUEST[q]%' OR LName LIKE '%$_REQUEST[q]%' ORDER BY id DESC");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1>Customers</h1>
            <p><a class="btn create" href="createcustomer.php">CREATE</a></p>
            <?php
            if (!$select->num_rows) {
                echo '<p>', 'No records', '</p>';
            }else{
            ?>
                <table border="1" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Alt Phone</th>
                        <th>Job Address</th>
                        <th>Billing Address</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Alt Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    while ($row = $select->fetch_object()) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->FName;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->LName;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->Phone;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->AltPhone;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->JobAddress;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->BillingAddress;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->Email;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->AltEmail;?></td>

                        <td><a class="btn read" href="viewcustomer.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>">READ</a>&nbsp;<a class="btn update" href="editcustomer.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>">UPDATE</a>&nbsp;<a class="btn delete" href="deletecustomer.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>">DELETE</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </table>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            # Search form that needs tied to $search
            <input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" name="search" />

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've no form tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need verify if the form is sent in your php code:

```
<?php

require 'db/connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['q'])) {

$q = $_POST['q'];

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE '%$q%' OR LName LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY id DESC");

} else {

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC");

}

?>
```

And you need change your code to add a form

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" name="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and I get an error '"Notice: Undefined variable: select in C:\wamp\www\customers.php on line 28"' In addition, at the top of the screen, it looks like there is a formatting error, because it shows the following end of code line text : 'query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE '%$q%' OR LName LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY id DESC"); } else { $select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC"); } ?>' P.S. : Line 28 is as follows : 'if (!$select->num_rows) {'

Comment: @Steven I edit my answer, try now, and let my know if the problem is solve

Comment: This works beautifully.  Thank you very much!!!! If you let me know your paypal email, I would love to buy you a drink :D

Answer (score 1):

I guess `'%$_REQUEST[q]%'` would give you a problem, because you want to access `$_REQUEST['q']` instead of `$_REQUEST[q]`.

Replacing it with `'%" . $_REQUEST['q'] . "%'` should be a good start.
But you usually don't want to leave it like that, because this code is vulnerable to sql injections.

Therefore you should use the quote function:

```
$search = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $_REQUEST['q'] . "%") . " OR LName LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $_REQUEST['q'] . "%") . " ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Next thing you want to do is checking whether the form input is set and to use the result of your search instead of the select statement without search parameters:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['q'])) {
    $q = "%" . $_REQUEST['q'] . "%";
    $select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE " . $db->quote($q) . " OR LName LIKE " . $db->quote($q) . " ORDER BY id DESC");
} else {
    $select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC");
}
```